# pdf download with utf 8

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, download

Helllo,

I hive pdf download script:

```
    $download_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test";
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];

    if(!$filename) die("I'm sorry, you must specify a file name to download.");

    if(eregi("\.\.", $filename)) die("I'm sorry, you may not download that file.");
    $file = str_replace("..", "", $filename);

    if(eregi("\.ht.+", $filename)) die("I'm sorry, you may not download that file.");
    $file = "$download_path/$file";
    if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");
    $type = filetype($file);
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $time = time();
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    readfile($file);
    ?>
```

and pdf search script:

```
 <?php 
    $directory = opendir('./test');
    $userid = "1487";
      while ($file = readdir($directory)) {
        if($file!="." && $file!=".." && strpos($file,$userid) !== false){
          echo '<a href="dl.php?filename='.$file.'">Download PDF</a><BR>';
        }
      }
    closedir($directory);
    ?>
```

Pdf filename is 1487LŪW, when start download file, file name changer for 1487L�W. And file don't find. Can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
```

Parameterised header values can't reliably include any non-ASCII character. Or at least not until everyone supports [RFC 5987](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5987.txt).

As a workaround until then, omit the `filename` parameter from the `Content-Disposition` header and instead include the filename as a trailing path part when you create a link to the document. For example:

```
http://example.com/dl.php/1487L%C5%AAW?filename=1487L%C5%AAW
```

The browser will pick up the last part of the path as the default filename. Including UTF-8 characters here is more reliable cross-browser than what you can do with the Content-Disposition header today.

You also need to URL-encode any characters you're putting into a URL parameter, and HTML-encode any value you're including in an HTML attribute (or text content), so putting it together you'd want something like:

```
$url = "dl.php/'.rawurlencode($file).'?filename='.rawurlencode($file);
echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'">Download PDF</a>';
```

(You could potentially cut down on the duplication by reading the trailing path part from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` rather than the get-parameter, if you know you're going to be running on a server where that variable is available.)